# Websence has blocked a website classifying it as uncategorized

Tags: block

Websence has blocked a website classifying it as uncategorized. But it is an Educational Website for an NGO named DigitaleSchool.in

Could you please help me with this ?

Thanks, 
Animesh

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for their database to be updated with your site.

They [provide instructions on how to request they add a site](https://www.websense.com/support/article/kbarticle/How-To-Submit-Uncategorized-Sites?popup=true).